# Why Selenium web-driver is not able to get 'tags' from aspx web page?

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, selenium, webdriver

Selenium is not able to get any **tag** like "*table*" or "*a*" from asp page. I also tried getting "*body*" tag, In that case it recognizes but throws exception as below:

```
> Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException:
> Element bel ongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to
> its containing frame to use it    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
> erro rResponse)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
> driverCommandToExecu te, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.GetAttribute(String
> attributeName)
```

C# code I have used is :

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(@"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\rwyq8vbx.default");  
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"), firefoxProfile);
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"http://epmweb.apac.bbc.com/pwa/_layouts/pwa/mytssummary.aspx");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        List<IWebElement> frameset = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe")).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(frameset.Count);
        foreach (var v in frameset)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("fName : " + v.GetAttribute("name"));
        }
        IWebElement[] rows = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("body")).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(rows.Length);
        foreach (var v in rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name : "+v.GetAttribute("id"));
        }
```

> frameset count it gives zero and rows length 1.

Apparently when I click view page source & save that page as html. I am able to get tags.

Any help , What am I missing here ?

EDIT :: I tried getting webpage what selenium is getting as web page. It returns :`

```
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> <html
> xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>My Timesheets -
> Project Web Access</title><link
> href="chrome://ietab2/skin/ietab-favicon-iedoc.png" rel="icon" />
> </head> <body onload="window.setTimeout(function() { init(); },0);"
> style="margin:0; padding:0;overflow:hidden">
> 
> <script type="text/javascript"> var gIETab = null;
> 
> function init(){
>     gIETab = document.getElementById("IETab2");
>     try {
>         // This is needed to avoid an "Activate Plugin" prompt in Fx 27+.
>         // It's not documented, thus the try/catch for back-compat
>         gIETab.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIObjectLoadingContent).playPlugin();
>     } catch(ex) {
>     }
> 
>     if(!gIETab || !gIETab.navigate)
>     {         // Wait for it to show up
>       window.setTimeout(function() { init(); }, 200);         return;     }
> 
>     var m=/(\?url=)(\S+)$/.exec(document.location.href);
>     if(m)
>     {
>         var url = decodeURI(m[2]);
>         if ((url.indexOf("about:") == 0) || (url.indexOf("chrome://") == 0))
>             url = 'http://www.ietab.net/ie-tab-v2-documentation?from=' + url;
>         gIETab.navigate(url);
>     } }
> 
> var IETabCalls = {    goBack: function() {        gIETab.goBack();    },
> 
>   goForward: function() {         gIETab.goForward();     },
> 
>   navigate: function(url) {       gIETab.navigate(url);   },
> 
>   refresh: function() {       gIETab.refresh();   },
> 
>   stop: function() {      gIETab.stop();  },
> 
>   saveAs: function() {        gIETab.saveAs();    },
> 
>   print: function() {         gIETab.print();     },
> 
>   printSetup: function() {        gIETab.printSetup();    },
> 
>   printPreview: function() {      gIETab.printPreview();  },
> 
>   viewSource: function() {        gIETab.viewSource();    },
> 
>   find: function() {      gIETab.find();  },
> 
>   cut: function() {       gIETab.cut();   },
> 
>   copy: function() {      gIETab.copy();  },
> 
>   paste: function() {         gIETab.paste();     },
> 
>   selectAll: function() {         gIETab.selectAll();     },
> 
>   focus: function() {         if (!gIETab) {          // It might not have loaded
> yet, wait for the control to fully initialize
>           window.setTimeout(function() { IETabCalls.focus(); }, 100);         }
>       else {          gIETab.focus();         }   } }
> 
> window.onpageshow = function(e) { if (e.persisted)
> window.setTimeout(function() { init(); }, 0); }
> 
> function createIETab() {
>     var obj = document.createElement("object");
>     obj.id = "IETab2";
>     obj.style.width = "100%";
>     obj.style.height = "100%";
>     // Waterfox/x64 example:
>     //   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20121026 Firefox/16.0
>     // Firefox/x32 on Win64:
>     //   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/17.0 Firefox/17.0
>     // Firefox/x32 on Win32
>     //   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
>     //
>     if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win64; x64;") != -1)
>         obj.setAttribute("type", "application/ietab2_x64");
>     else
>         obj.setAttribute("type", "application/ietab2");
>     document.body.appendChild(obj); } // Navigation happens later, but create the IE Tab object immediately createIETab(); </script><object
> id="IETab2" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
> type="application/ietab2"></object>
> 
> 
> </body></html>
```

`

But when I check manually page source, It looks normal, as it should be.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be an **"iframe" tag**. It can be a **frame** tag as well.. Have you looked out for that possibility ?

Comment: No "frame" tag either. It is not able to get tag only when running on website. If I check page source and save it at local as html page , I am able to get tags. Also It is able to get body tag while running on website but not its id or text. It is actually an internal website. That should not matter, right ? Some security is enabled I guess, When I open same link with chrome it gives error,"At least Internet Explorer version 6 is needed to use Project Web Access."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved :** It was happening because page was being opened using IE tab in Firefox. Firefox Selenium add-on doesn't work there. One need to open IE Driver and profile set to dontNet *Client*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use switchTo to switch into iframes.
See http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frameName");
```

Comment: There is no "Iframe" Tag. Count of frameset comes out to be zero. Have a look on code. (7th line)